# How to replace the buttons (attachment) only w/ Slack interactive buttons response

Tags: slack-api

I've managed to create a simple interactive button Slack app using a Google Apps Script (GAS).

I know how to replace the original message w/ the response, but I would like to replace only the buttons, as demonstrated (but not clearly explained) multiple places in the Slack Interactive Button documentation:
https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#crafting_your_message

I'd like to do what's demonstrated here: 
https://a.slack-edge.com/dcb1/img/api/message_guidelines/Example_6.gif

Is this an update of the original message, a replacement of the original message with identical text but different attachment, ...?

My current interactive buttons message code looks like this:

```
function sendMsgWithButton() {

// slack channel url (where to send the message)
var slackUrl = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/...";

// message text  
var messageData = {
"text": "Here's your interactive buttons message.",
"attachments": [
    {
        "text": "Can you click the button?",
        "fallback": "Sorry, no support for buttons.",
        "callback_id": "ptNotificationButtonResponse",
        "color": "#3AA3E3",
        "attachment_type": "default",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "userResponse",
                "text": "OK",
                "style": "primary",
                "type": "button",
                "value": "ok"
            }
                   ]
    }
                ]
}

// format for Slack
var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(messageData)
 };    

// post to Slack
UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackUrl, options);
}
```

My current action URL code right now looks like this:

```
function doPost() {

var replyMessage = {"replace_original": true,
                    "response_type": "in_channel",
                    "text": "I see you clicked the button."
                   };

 return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(replyMessage)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);     
}
```

Instead of replacing the entire original message, I'd like to replace just the buttons with something like a checkbox and confirmation message as demonstrated in the gif above.

Thanks!

Comment: This should be slack feature to replace buttons with something meaningful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only replace the complete message, not just a part.

There are two options to update the original message:

1. Respond to the Slack request with `{"replace_original": true}`
2. Use [`chat.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update)

If your original message was not of type `ephemeral` you will get a copy of the original message as part of the payload from Slack in the `original_message` property, which can be helpful to update the exchange the original message.

See [this page](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#how_to_respond_to_message_button_actions) in the Slack documentation as reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help - we're going w/ option 1.

Comment: @Matt Can you share your working `doPost` code? I'm still having the same issue you had when you posted this question

Comment: @baskInEminence - I just ended up replacing everything for testing, and then I never implemented it, so I don't have any code to share.

Comment: @Matt No worries, I actually figured it out and created a [Medium](https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/what-i-learned-when-creating-an-intelligent-slack-app-with-javascript-and-google-scripts-3d3014e9b328) article linking to my [repo](https://github.com/sp71/ChoreTinder#chore-tinder).

Comment: So it's fake on slacks documentation? @baskInEminence (I can't find the part where you explain how to update a part of a message)

Comment: @jens I was curious about this too. Turns out you can accomplish this (replace buttons with message while leaving original message text intact) by deleting the actions and then appending a newline plus an additional message to the original message text

Comment: Looking at it I think they actually use the `footer` and `footer_icon` fields to achieve that result