# Slack Interactive message menu select multiple

Tags: select, menu, message, slack

I want to develop a feature such a way that user can select multiple options from message menu. Is it possible to select multiple options from the interactive menu at the same time ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can currently only select one option. Slack does not support choosing more than one option in a message.

But there are 2 alternatives:

### Dialogs

[Dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) are modal and allow you to use up to 10 elements each including select menus. And they have a "submit" and "cancel" button.

This allows you to implement exactly what you are asking, but your selects would be shown in a separate Dialog window and not directly as part of your message. You also need some extra functionality to connect the Dialog with your message, e.g. by having a button in the message that opens the Dialog.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242419/how-to-combine-slash-commands-buttons-and-dialogs-for-a-menu) on how to combine slash commands, buttons and dialogs.

### Chaining message with selects

Another alternative is to chain selects in multiple messages one after the other for the user. This can be done by replacing the original posted message with a new message after each user interactions.

So after the user selected the first drop down your app shows him the 2nd menu and so on. Finally you would show the user a submit or cancel button. You can of course also add some functionality to the workflow, e.g. have a cancel button for every step.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793220/how-to-replace-the-buttons-attachment-only-w-slack-interactive-buttons-respon/42793752#42793752) on how to replace the current message after the user clicked on a select.

Comment: @Pooja Nikam If this answer solved your questions, please consider marking it as solution. Thank you!

Comment: If slack is reading this, please - please add either multi-select or checkbox options to your API.  At the moment there is no good way to do this and honestly this answer doesn't do a great job of providing the needed interactivity (although its likely the best possible answer based on what is available today).

Comment: @BradenRockwellNapier Thanks for your feedback. I added more details on the solutions and also added that you can use Dialogs as alternative.

Comment: Well the good news is that they listened.  If you look at their roadmap they have multi step modals listed as coming soon as well as more interactive elements which sources tell me are likely to be radios and other things within blocks!