# How to combine slash commands, buttons and dialogs for a menu?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

My Slack app is started with a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), which then posts an ephemeral menu message to the user. That menu has some information and three message buttons.

Example:

[image]

- First button allows the user to close the menu
- Second button allows the user to start an action
- Third button allows the user to open a [dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) for changing
  options.

After the user submits the dialog I want to update the menu message to reflect the changes made in the dialog.

However, after the user submits the dialog I can no longer to update the message menu by responding to a Slack response as before.

How can I update the menu message with the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the connection with the initial slash command one needs to store the `response_url` of the last interactive action before opening the dialog.

In this example it will be in the interactive action request initiated after pressing the "Options" button. That `response_url` allows one to seamlessly continue the conversation that was started with the initial slash command.

The easiest approach for storing the `response_url` is to put it into the [`state`](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#state) property of the dialog, which will automatically be echoed back to the app with the [dialog submission request](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#response).

One needs to be careful not to confuse the `response_url` from the interactive action with the `response_url` from the dialog.

Also, the dialog cancel case is automatically handled, since in that case the user can continue working with the initial menu message.