# Open modal using Slack command

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-commands

I have a Slack command which displays a button. When I click on this button I need to display a modal. For this, after clicking it I do this:

```
const dialog = {
  callback_id: "submit-ticket",
  elements: [
    {
      hint: "30 second summary of the problem",
      label: "Title",
      name: "title",
      type: "text",
      value: "teste"
    },
    {
      label: "Description",
      name: "description",
      optional: true,
      type: "textarea"
    },
    {
      label: "Urgency",
      name: "urgency",
      options: [
        { label: "Low", value: "Low" },
        { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
        { label: "High", value: "High" }
      ],
      type: "select"
    }
  ],
  submit_label: "Submit",
  title: "Submit a helpdesk ticket"
};

const modalInfo = {
    dialog: JSON.stringify(dialog),
    token, // this is correct
    trigger_id: actionJSONPayload.trigger_id
  };


  // This is what I get confused with...

  // Method 1
  slack.dialog.open(modalInfo).catch(err => {
    console.log("ERROR: ", err);
  });
  // end method 1

  // Method 2
  sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(actionJSONPayload.response_url, modalInfo);

...

function sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(responseURL: any, JSONmessage: any) {
  const postOptions = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    json: JSONmessage,
    method: "POST",
    uri: responseURL
  };
  request(postOptions, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("----Error: ", error);
    }
  });
}
// end method 2
```

I get always `Error: invalid_trigger` using method1 when this trigger is something that my button is generating automatically.

Method 2 doesn't throw any error but doesn't open any modal/dialog either.

The official documentation is not quite clear and I don't know if I need to call dialog.open or views.open. Either way, the last one is not available from [Slack package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack)

This is also the button I'm displaying before anything:

```
const message = {
        attachments: [
          {
            actions: [
              {
                name: "send_sms",
                style: "danger",
                text: "Yes",
                type: "button",
                value: "yes"
              },
              {
                name: "no",
                text: "No",
                type: "button",
                value: "no"
              }
            ],
            attachment_type: "default",
            callback_id: "alert",
            color: "#3AA3E3",
            fallback: "We could not load the options. Try later",
            text: "Do you want to alert by SMS about P1 error/fix?"
          }
        ],
        text: "P1 SMSs"
      };
```

Comment: This answer describes how to combine interactive menus and dialogs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242419/how-to-combine-slash-commands-buttons-and-dialogs-for-a-menu Does that solve your issue?

Comment: so that means that I cannot make a call to the API using that library, that I should do it using the url from the payload?

Comment: no. You call dialog.open to open the Dialog. The response_url is needed to update the initial message after the dialog is submitted.

Comment: but when I call `dialog.open` is when it fails

Comment: I updated my question with the 2 methods I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy a modal from [here](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=modal&view=%7B%22type%22%3A%22modal%22%2C%22title%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22My%20App%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22submit%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Submit%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22close%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Cancel%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22blocks%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text_input%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22title%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22What%20do%20you%20want%20to%20ask%20of%20the%20world%3F%22%7D%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Title%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22multi_channels_select%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22channels%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Where%20should%20the%20poll%20be%20sent%3F%22%7D%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Channel(s)%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text_input%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22option_1%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22First%20option%22%7D%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Option%201%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text_input%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22option_2%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22How%20many%20options%20do%20they%20need%2C%20really%3F%22%7D%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Option%202%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22actions%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22add_option%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Add%20another%20option%20%20%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

```
const headers = {
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  }
};

const modalInfo = {
        "token": token,
        "trigger_id": reqBody.trigger_id,
        "view": slack.modal
      };

      axios
        .post("https://slack.com/api/views.open", modalInfo, headers)
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data;
          if (!data.ok) {
            return data.error;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("-Error: ", error);
        });
```

But most importantly, when we do some changes to our app we need to **reinstall** it and also when we do it, the token **changes** and this is something I couldn't find on the documentation