# How to get data from multiple interactive blocks all at once?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am creating a slack app where people can schedule when they are on call. I use two date pickers to specify the start date and the end date, and a button to submit the data. What I can't figure out is if the date picker `selected_date` data can be sent along with the button press, as only `initial_date` is shown in the block JSON.

Here is the response I get from pressing the button:

```
[{'action_id': 'hjy',
              'action_ts': '1563202745.027278',
              'block_id': 'uPBVi',
              'text': {'emoji': True, 'text': 'Submit', 'type': 'plain_text'},
              'type': 'button',
              'value': 'yes'}],
 'api_app_id': 'AKL2KTU75',
 'channel': {'id': 'CKVM4FJM6', 'name': 'general'},
 'container': {'channel_id': 'CKVM4FJM6',
               'is_ephemeral': False,
               'message_ts': '1563200576.002500',
               'type': 'message'},
 'message': {'blocks': [{'block_id': 'tgnS',
                         'text': {'text': 'Hello+<@UKVM4F04Q>!+select+the+days+you+will+be+available+through+below',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'block_id': 'bSu1B', 'type': 'divider'},
                        {'accessory': {'action_id': '5k6C',
                                       'initial_date': '2019-7-15',
                                       'placeholder': {'emoji': True,
                                                       'text': 'Select+a+date',
                                                       'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'datepicker'},
                         'block_id': 'CcW',
                         'text': {'text': 'Start+Date',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'accessory': {'action_id': 'D5UB',
                                       'initial_date': '2019-7-15',
                                       'placeholder': {'emoji': True,
                                                       'text': 'Select+a+date',
                                                       'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'datepicker'},
                         'block_id': 'Rpo5',
                         'text': {'text': 'End+Date',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'block_id': 'uPBVi',
                         'elements': [{'action_id': 'hjy',
                                       'text': {'emoji': True,
                                                'text': 'Submit',
                                                'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'button',
                                       'value': 'yes'},
                                      {'action_id': '6t/g',
                                       'text': {'emoji': True,
                                                'text': 'Cancel',
                                                'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'button',
                                       'value': 'no'}],
                         'type': 'actions'}],
             'bot_id': 'BKZJLQGG6',
             'subtype': 'bot_message',
             'text': "This+content+can't+be+displayed.",
             'ts': '1563200576.002500',
             'type': 'message',
             'username': 'pythonapp'},
 'response_url': 'https://hooks.slack.com/actions/TKV776BD2/688472980689/5Y52XBs2bUqdnOlwWLq0vWDp',
 'team': {'domain': 'testing-o4a6006', 'id': 'TKV776BD2'},
 'token': '[leaving out]',
 'trigger_id': '694351571380.675245215444.f509bc26fc7ac4c230627e6b32fca516',
 'type': 'block_actions',
 'user': {'id': 'UKVM4F04Q',
          'name': 'noahbraunfeld',
          'team_id': 'TKV776BD2',
          'username': 'noahbraunfeld'}}
```

And here is the response I get from the datepickers:

```
{'actions': [{'action_id': '5k6C',
              'action_ts': '1563201722.414594',
              'block_id': 'CcW',
              'initial_date': '2019-7-15',
              'selected_date': '2019-07-14',
              'type': 'datepicker'}],
 'api_app_id': 'AKL2KTU75',
 'channel': {'id': 'CKVM4FJM6', 'name': 'general'},
 'container': {'channel_id': 'CKVM4FJM6',
               'is_ephemeral': False,
               'message_ts': '1563200576.002500',
               'type': 'message'},
 'message': {'blocks': [{'block_id': 'tgnS',
                         'text': {'text': 'Hello+<@UKVM4F04Q>!+select+the+days+you+will+be+available+through+below',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'block_id': 'bSu1B', 'type': 'divider'},
                        {'accessory': {'action_id': '5k6C',
                                       'initial_date': '2019-7-15',
                                       'placeholder': {'emoji': True,
                                                       'text': 'Select+a+date',
                                                       'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'datepicker'},
                         'block_id': 'CcW',
                         'text': {'text': 'Start+Date',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'accessory': {'action_id': 'D5UB',
                                       'initial_date': '2019-7-15',
                                       'placeholder': {'emoji': True,
                                                       'text': 'Select+a+date',
                                                       'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'datepicker'},
                         'block_id': 'Rpo5',
                         'text': {'text': 'End+Date',
                                  'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                  'verbatim': False},
                         'type': 'section'},
                        {'block_id': 'uPBVi',
                         'elements': [{'action_id': 'hjy',
                                       'text': {'emoji': True,
                                                'text': 'Submit',
                                                'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'button',
                                       'value': 'yes'},
                                      {'action_id': '6t/g',
                                       'text': {'emoji': True,
                                                'text': 'Cancel',
                                                'type': 'plain_text'},
                                       'type': 'button',
                                       'value': 'no'}],
                         'type': 'actions'}],
             'bot_id': 'BKZJLQGG6',
             'subtype': 'bot_message',
             'text': "This+content+can't+be+displayed.",
             'ts': '1563200576.002500',
             'type': 'message',
             'username': 'pythonapp'},
 'response_url': '[leaving out]',
 'team': {'domain': 'testing-o4a6006', 'id': 'TKV776BD2'},
 'token': '[leaving out]',
 'trigger_id': '696646850567.675245215444.317894098ee3aa6938c5c40d4107fb68',
 'type': 'block_actions',
 'user': {'id': '[leaving out]',
          'name': 'noahbraunfeld',
          'team_id': 'TKV776BD2',
          'username': 'noahbraunfeld'}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack Interactive message menu select multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523512/slack-interactive-message-menu-select-multiple)

Comment: Hi there. I linked you the answer with talks about menus, but all interactive message elements in Slack behave the same.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken thanks! I will just update the message after the user selects the dates

Comment: @NoahBraunfeld did you get it working?