# Submit slack modal with block elements

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

On my modal view I have two `datePicker` elements. I know that payload with action information is sent after each interaction, but is it possible to pass all selected values after form submission?
I only came up with solution where after each interaction selected value is cached on the server side and bound to `view_id`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack Interactive message menu select multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523512/slack-interactive-message-menu-select-multiple)

Comment: The Datepicker is currently not available in Slack Dialogs, so your only option is #2 from the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can achieve this by placing your interaction component inside input block type. Slack documentation says.

Any interactive components used within input blocks will not send this block_actions payload. They are included in view_submission payloads only.

https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/block-actions

An [example](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=modal&view=%7B%22type%22%3A%22modal%22%2C%22title%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Workplace%20check-in%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22submit%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Submit%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22close%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Cancel%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22blocks%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Awave%3A%20Hey%20David!%5Cn%5CnWe%27d%20love%20to%20hear%20from%20you%20how%20we%20can%20make%20this%20place%20the%20best%20place%20you%E2%80%99ve%20ever%20worked.%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22You%20enjoy%20working%20here%20at%20Pistachio%20%26%20Co%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22static_select%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20an%20item%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Strongly%20Agree%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-0%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Agree%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Neither%20agree%20nor%20disagree%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-2%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Disagree%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-3%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Strongly%20disagree%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-4%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22What%20do%20you%20want%20for%20our%20team%20weekly%20lunch%3F%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22multi_static_select%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20your%20favorites%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Apizza%3A%20Pizza%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-0%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Afried_shrimp%3A%20Thai%20food%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Adesert_island%3A%20Hawaiian%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-2%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Ameat_on_bone%3A%20Texas%20BBQ%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-3%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Ahamburger%3A%20Burger%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-4%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Ataco%3A%20Tacos%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-5%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Agreen_salad%3A%20Salad%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-6%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Astew%3A%20Indian%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22value-7%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22What%20can%20we%20do%20to%20improve%20your%20experience%20working%20here%3F%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22datepicker%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22action-123%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Anything%20else%20you%20want%20to%20tell%20us%3F%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22datepicker%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22action-123%22%7D%2C%22optional%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D) I have created in block kit

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to receive the `block_actions` events, then use `input` blocks like GJoshi suggests.

But if you do need the `block_actions` events, then you cannot use `input` blocks (per https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#interactions).  In that case, you can add the value to the [private_metadata](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/views#fields) field via the [views.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.update) call.  When the user clicks the submit button, the [view_submission](https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/views#view_submission) event payload will contain the `private_metadata` field.

Answer (score 1):

For folks who stumble upon this as I did, the answers above are no longer up to date since now slack allows input blocks to dispatch block actions. The approach of using [private_metadata](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/views#fields) is still relevant in some scenarios, but just receiving block actions makes life much easier.

Simply set "dispatch_action" to true when defining a specific [input block](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#input) to receive a payload whenever it gets updated.

Once the user submits, you will still have access to all the values of the input data