# Slack API to add attachments to user message without altering user's text

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

How do I make a slack app add attachments to a message without editing user's text or showing the (edited) flag on the message? I'm trying to do same as Github app in slack that adds attachments to the existing message.

**GitHub Example**
[image]

**Current Behaviour** 
[image]

**Code**

```
this.rtmClient.on('message', this.slackMessage);
...
await this.webClient.chat.update({
  ts: message.ts,
  channel: message.channel,
  text: message.text, // tried ommiting but just remove's text
  attachments: [
    {
      color: '#2d9ee0',
      fallback: 'text',
      text: 'text',
      mrkdwn_in: ['text'],
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Github is not adding an attachment, it is using Slack's [app unfurling](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling) feature.

This is a special case that allows apps to add custom attachments to app-related URLs. (e.g. a github URL). Whenever someone posts such a URL the app is triggered and can provide a custom attachment related to the URL. Similar to when you post a GIF.

In general you can NOT add attachments to random messages without editing them. Sorry.

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but what you can do is reply to a message with a new message that replaces the first one. It then looks like it added an attachment, when in reality it just replaced the original message. That works with slash command and interactive message replies. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793220/how-to-replace-the-buttons-attachment-only-w-slack-interactive-buttons-respon/42793752#42793752) for details.