# Slack - chatbot dialog with button

Tags: chatbot, slack, slack-api

In slack is possible to use attachments to create buttons in a chat (https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons).

How can I click in the button and use the text button in chat? Don't use link or redirect, just use the button text in the chat.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure I understand what you are asking. To clarify: The standard message buttons do not use links or redirects. Instead: when a user clicks on it your app will receive a special HTTP request from Slack. Note that there also is variant called link button that works differently.

Comment: Hi @ErikKalkoken, Im needing to continue the dialog. Then, when I click in the button, the button value goes to the text, continuing the dialog (dont doing a request).

Comment: ok thanks. I think I understand now what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to update your chat message after a user clicks the button.

Here is how this would work with Slack:

1. Your app post a message with a message button in a channel
2. User clicks on button
3. Your app gets [interaction request](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity#request) from Slack
4. Your apps replies to the Slack request to update the message content
   (e.g. text) by replacing it with a new message.

This is how this works with Slack and its the only approach. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793220/how-to-replace-the-buttons-attachment-only-w-slack-interactive-buttons-respon/42793752#42793752) on the same topic.

Comment: Just to check if I undestand. To disable the buttons, I need to update the message with new layout. And to use the buttons, I need to use another endpoint, I can`t use the button just to put the text in the chat, right?

Comment: correct and correct. you need an endpoint to enable any kind of functionality with message buttons.

Comment: I get it... Thanks bro!